# Is every function in the class with `self` an instance variable even if it just does something unrelated to the specific instance?

Tags: python

So would this be an instance variable or a class variable?

```
def f(self):   # is this instance.f an instance variable?
    return 'hello world'
```

the `instance.f()` command returns the same thing for all instances so is this unique to the instances or the class?

Comment: `f` is a method, not a variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if it does something unrelated to the specific instance, it always receives a different instance as the `self` argument. It might be better to use a static method instead:

```
@staticmethod
def f():
    return 'hello world'
```

Now it is unique:

```
class C:
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'

a = C()
b = C()
print(a.f == b.f)  # False

class C:
    @staticmethod
    def f():
        return 'hello world'

a = C()
b = C()
print(a.f == b.f)  # True
```